# Unit-testing $timeout execution inside an async call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I'm trying to unit-test a piece of my code contained inside an async call, like this:

```
function init() {
  asyncFunc().then(function (data) {        
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.isInside = true;
    });
  });
}
```

The whole code:

```
(function (angular) {
  // Create module
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

  // Controller which counts changes to its "name" member
  myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.isInside = false;

    init();

    function init() {
      asyncFunc().then(function (data) {        
        $timeout(function () {
          $scope.isInside = true;
        });
      });
    }

    function asyncFunc() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $http.get('https://httpbin.org/get').success((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        }).error((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
      });
    }
  }]);

})(angular);
```

My intention is to test the $scope.isInside value. This is my test:

```
describe('myApp', function () {
  var scope,
      controller;
  beforeEach(function () {
    module('myApp');
  });

  describe('MyCtrl', function () {
    var $httpBackend, endpointCall, $timeout;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_, _$timeout_) {
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      $timeout = _$timeout_;

      endpointCall = $httpBackend.expect('GET', 'https://httpbin.org/get').respond({data: 'data'});
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
        '$scope': scope
      });

    }));

    it('initializes', function () {
      $httpBackend.flush();
      $timeout.flush();
      expect(scope.isInside).toBe(true);
    });

  });

});
```

The test is failing, the value is "false", but I'm expecting to see a "true" there.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/KarmaCop213/tj6akcyk/1/

Comment: The fiddle is cool. It would be *even cooler* if it were here, on-site, using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: I'm not sure you need that new Promise as $http.get already returns promise. When updated like that http://jsfiddle.net/tj6akcyk/4/ the test passes. probably one more digest cycle will solve the problem in its original variant. also you can  wrap expect in timeout